# Is Regex the best way to split from one string series into many series with parts of the string?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to clean up some data using pandas. The data is downloadable [here](https://expirebox.com/download/06a87641025c35d7041a51cba0a63b62.html).

It is price data but some users have entered additional data types into the field which I'd like to move into it's own series. Immediately regex popped into my head but I'd like to find out if there are other easier options?

The problematic data appears in this format:

`99,0006,000                 on 13-7-2018`

The good data appears in this format:

`99,500`

The output I'm trying to create is 3 new series

Col1 : 13-7-2018

Col2 : 99,000

Col3 : 6,000

I need to split the date out but also split the 99,000 and 6,000 as these are two separate numbers (people have entered price ranges). Is splitting mid-number when the values changes every time even possible in regex?

Any suggestions on how to best perform this are welcome :)

Comment: What happens when got this kind of data `99,0516,000                 on 13-7-2018`? Is it than 99,05  and 16,000 or 99,051 and 6,000?

Comment: How have you tried to process this so far? Do you have a regex that isn't working? Also if you could edit a sample of the data into your post that would be helpful - I'm not super keen on links to unknown websites!

Comment: @asongtoruin I've not made an attempt at it yet. I'm quite new to coding and realised that sometimes my approach is wrong as I don't have the experience to know what tools are available. As this seemed quite tricky I thought I'd ask the community first. Regex was my first thought but not sure if it can do what I need. The series is basically made up of the two types of data I've put in the description above.

Comment: @nauer good question :)  what I've noticed is that there are always 3 digits after the comma. The digits change but it's always 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be sloppy but it's the best way I could figure out how to do this

```
splitprice_pt1 = pricedata.str.split(r'\bon\b', expand=True)[0]
#split the numbers on the 'on' text and selecting the first part
split_KE_Date = pricedata.str.split(r'\bon\b', expand=True)[1]
#split the numbers on the 'on' text and selecting the second part
split_KE_Price = splitprice_pt1.str.split(r'^([^,]*,[^,]{3})', expand=True)[0]
#split the numbers on the 3 digits after comma and selecting the first part
range_KE_Price = splitprice_pt1.str.split(r'^([^,]*,[^,]{3})', expand=True)[1]
#split the numbers on the 3 digits after comma and selecting the second part
```

Answer (score 0):

Use splicing for the first two numbers:

```
str1 = "99,0006,000                 on 13-7-2018"
num1 = str1[0:6]
num2 = str2[6:11]
num1 = 99,000
num2 = 6,000
```

And then regex for dates

```
date_pt = re.compile("[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}")
date = re.search(str1)
```

Using date.start() and date.end(), you'll get the positions of the date in the string. Use slicing again to access it.

Note that I have answered this considering the numbers length remain the same.

Comment: Can this be run on a series do data?

Comment: Sorry could you elaborate?